# Как добавить массив string в другой на c#?

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть два таких массива:

```
string[] a = File.ReadAllLines(@"a.txt");
string[] b = File.ReadAllLines(@"b.txt");
```

Как в массив a добавить массив b?

Comment: Возможно дубль вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/merging-two-arrays-in-net

Comment: @ВадимАлександру этот ссылка на английский SO, дубли считаются, только в рамках этого сайта, русского Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;
....
a = a.Concat(b).ToArray();
```

Если без промежуточных массивов, то

```
var a = File.ReadLines(@"a.txt")
.Concat(File.ReadLines(@"b.txt"))
.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Число элементов в массиве неизменно, нужно создавать новый массив:

```
using System.IO;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(@"a.txt", Encoding.UTF8),
    sr2 = new StreamReader(@"b.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
sb.Append(sr1.ReadToEnd());
sb.Append("\n");
sb.Append(sr2.ReadToEnd());
string[] result = sb.ToString().Split('\n');
for(int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    result[i] = result[i].Trim('\r');
```

Comment: Для стримридера UTF8 - кодировка по умолчанию, не нужно ее явно указывать. `Split('\n');` - а с `\r` что будете делать.

Comment: @aepot Добавил `Trim`